# Is there a way to create errors in GCP Error Reporting without Error Reporting associating them together?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-error-reporting

Often GCP Error Reporting's groupings are helpful in making the tool coherent and allowing for quick identification of issues; however, sometimes I would like to make sure that Error Reporting creates a separate group for a specific error and does not group it together, for instance the failure of a system. Is it possible, through the ErrorReporting Node.js client (we are using Node.js Cloud Functions) or otherwise to force-create an Error and ensure that it is not grouped with other, similar stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting are grouped by following these general patterns:

> - Exceptions are grouped together if they have the same exception type and similar stacks.
> - The stack trace is ignored for exceptions that are typically unrelated to the source location where they occur.
> - Errors without an exception stack are grouped together if they were created by the same log statement, approximated by the source location it was reported from (`reportLocation`).

You can also create a custom error reporting for Node.js by using the [client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-error-reporting). Refer to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/nodejs) in setting up error reporting for Node.js

Comment: I am looking for a way to bypass this behavior.